# angular2 after upgrade error ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

after upgrading to the latest angular cli. i have errors that i didn't had before. one of them is:
ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

it refers to this line in my users service:

```
  private dbRef: firebase.database.Reference;

  constructor(
  ) { 
   this.dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
  }
```

it worked before.

in my app.module i have:
import { AngularFireModule,AuthProviders,AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

and initialization in the imports    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig,momFirebaseAuthConfig),

in my package.json i have:
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "firebase": "^3.6.6",

how to fix the issue?

Comment: Maybe try to update `firebase` too. Do you have imported firebase in your component? (Please show imports of component too)

Comment: it is a service. and i have this import and it worked before the upgrade: import {AngularFire,FirebaseListObservable,FirebaseObjectObservable,AngularFireDatabase,FirebaseRef} from 'angularfire2';

Comment: the import of firebase worked

Answer (score 0):

You must `Inject angularfire2 service` to your component ([@Inject and @Injectable by Rangle.io](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/angular2/inject_and_injectable.html)):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'project-name-app',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class MyApp {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.items = af.database.list('/items');
  }
}
```